# Publish on CreateUsingInMemory bus crashes application

Tags: .net, masstransit

The following code just crashes the application, no errors are caught and the application simply shuts down when calling **Publish**. 
What I'm really trying to do is to perform unittests, this code is just the abstract in order to provide a clean example. When I run the corresponding code as a unittest, I get an errormessage saying that the thread is aborting. The code is using version 3.5.6 of the MassTransit nuget package.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;

namespace CustomerService.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => PerformMassTransitTest()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }

        public static async void PerformMassTransitTest()
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(config =>
            {
                config.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue", endpoint => { endpoint.Consumer<TestMessageConsumeer>(); });
            });

            try
            {
                await busControl.StartAsync();
                await busControl.Publish(new TestMessage());
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(err);
            }
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestMessage
    {
    }

    public class TestMessageConsumeer : IConsumer<TestMessage>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestMessage> context)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Consuming");
            return Task.FromResult("Consumeed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your async method to be awaited properly, it must return `Task`. Since you return `void`, there is nothing to await so the thread gets disposed. This is not related to MassTransit, just regular async/await thing.

When you change your method to return task, you can simplify the call by using `TaskUtil.Await(() => PerformMassTransitTest());`

As per unit tests, you can use the bus harness to test your consumers, like it is shown [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/Testing/ConsumerTest_Specs.cs). The documentation is lagging behind but it is coming.

Comment: Thank you, perfect, sometimes you don't see the forest for all the trees :) Works like a charm!

Comment: @MorganArvander it would be nice if you can accept and upvote the answer then :)